# Same VPS, 2 IP Addresses, Httpd and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

Is something like below possible?

Same VPS with 2 IP Addresses associated with it.

Apache Httpd -> bound to one of the IP Addresses on port 80 -> serving domain.com
Apache Tomcat -> bound to another IP Address on port 80 -> subdomain.domain.com

If yes, can you please point me to a link which achieves something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config of each software, you would bind the software to its appropriate IP.

Tomcat -> http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Apache -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Comment: ok. I think this should solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you consider using Apache to front-end both sites, and proxy the subdomain connections using something like `mod_proxy_ajp`.  This eliminates the requirement for a second front-end IP, and most folks will agree that Tomcat isn't great for a frontend.